# Medieval orthography

Tags: code-golf, string

## Task

Your task is to convert a text into medieval orthography.

## Details

1. `j` is converted to `i` and `J` to `I`.
2. `u` and `U` at the beginning of words are converted to `v` and `V` respectively.
3. `v` and `V` at anywhere except the beginning of words are converted to `u` and `U` respectively.
4. `s` is converted to `ſ` (U+017F) unless at the end of the word or preceded by another `s`.

## Specs

- A word is defined as a sequence of letters in `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`.
- All words will have at least two letters.
- The input will only consist of **printable ASCII characters** (U+0020 - U+007E).
- There will be no occurrences of more than two consecutive `s`. That is, `sss` will not be a substring of the input.

## Testcases

Individual words:

```
Input       Output
------------------------
Joy         Ioy
joy         ioy
Universe    Vniuerſe
universe    vniuerſe
Success     Succeſs
successfull ſucceſsfull
Supervise   Superuiſe
supervise   ſuperuiſe
Super-vise  Super-viſe
I've        I've
majors      maiors
UNIVERSE    VNIUERSE
0universe   0vniuerſe
0verify     0verify
I0ve        I0ve
_UU_          _VU_
_VV_          _VU_
ss_         ſs_
```

Whole paragraph:

```
Input:  Christian Reader, I have for thy use collected this small Concordance, with no small labour. For being to comprise much in little roome, I was to make choyse of the most principall and usefull places, and to rank them under such words as I thought most essentiall and materiall in the sentence, because the scant roome allotted unto me, would not permit that I should expresse them under every word in the verse, as it is the manner in large Concordances.

Output: Chriſtian Reader, I haue for thy vſe collected this ſmall Concordance, with no ſmall labour. For being to compriſe much in little roome, I was to make choyſe of the moſt principall and vſefull places, and to rank them vnder ſuch words as I thought moſt eſsentiall and materiall in the ſentence, becauſe the ſcant roome allotted vnto me, would not permit that I ſhould expreſse them vnder euery word in the verſe, as it is the manner in large Concordances.
```

The [SHA-256](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) hash of the output of the last testcase is:

```
5641899e7d55e6d1fc6e9aa4804f2710e883146bac0e757308afc58521621644
```

## Disclaimer

Medievall orthographie is not that conſtante. Pleaſe do not complayne if you ſhall ſee olde bookes with a different orthographie.

Comment: "You are allowed to use f instead of ſ in the output." So there's basically no incentive to use ſ since it takes more bytes.

Comment: @Fatalize Fair point. Removed that one.

Comment: @LeakyNun Can we then count `ſ` as 1  byte?

Comment: there is actually incentive in the form of ff being changed to fs in some algorithms if ſ was not used

Comment: @R.Kap Nope. – –

Comment: @PeterTaylor Clarified.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks, added.

Comment: Shouldn't `Super-vise` become `Super-viſe`?

Comment: What do you mean by `beginning` and `end` of words? Does that mean the first characters, the first `n` characters, etc.?

Comment: @R.Kap Beginning means the first letter; end means the last letter (is this so ambiguous?)

Comment: @R.Kap Yes, fixed.

Comment: How about `I0ve` as a test case?

Answer (score 3):

## SED, <strike>144 140</strike> 111 Bytes

saved 29 bytes thanks to NoOneIsHere

```
-r -e'y/j/i/g;y/J/I/g;s/ u/ v/g;s/ U/ V/g;s/^u/v/g;s/^U/V/g;s/([^s])s(\w)/\1ſ\2/g;s/(\w)v/\1u/g;s/(\w)V/\1U/g'
```

Comment: You brave, brave soul.

Comment: You can cut many bytes by using only 1 `-e`. Use `;`s inbetween statements.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3 (<strike>128</strike> 126 bytes)

```py
import re;lambda k:re.sub("(?<!s)s(?=[a-zA-Z])",'ſ',re.sub("(?i)j|(?<![a-z])u|(?<=[a-z])v",lambda c:chr(ord(c.group())^3),k))
```

`chr(ord(c.group())^3)` feels excessive to xor a single-character string, but maybe a real Pythonista can suggest a golf. However, it's very convenient that `^3` suffices to interchange `i <-> j` and `u <-> v`.

NB The only thing here which requires Python 3 is the Unicode character: Python 2 complains `Non-ASCII character '\xc5' <snip> but no encoding declared`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\b` since `\b` uses the definition of a word which includes digits and underscores.

Comment: @LeakyNun, hmm. While I'm looking for a fix, could you please add some test cases?

Comment: @R.Kap. `(?i)`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Wait, what does that do?

Comment: @R.Kap, it makes the regex case-insensitive.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Oh really? Wow, I did not know that. Do you mind if I use that in my answer?

Comment: @R.Kap, you won't find it easy because the `s` match is case-sensitive. I can use it because I've split out into two replacements.

Comment: All words will have at least two letters. (since you didn't join chat, can't find you in chat)

Comment: @LeakyNun, are you telling me this because you want me to change some of the test cases or because you've found a bug in my code?

Comment: Because you added `s_` as a testcase, which should really be undefined.

Comment: You can get this to work in python 2 by starting the file with the UTF-8 BOM `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`.

Comment: @xsot, this is a golf. If I can save 3 bytes by using a more recent version of the language, I will! But when I see answers which specify the version I'm curious to know what the new feature is which they rely on.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just thought to mention it so that those competing in python 2 can use your submission as a goal to beat.

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> 50 bytes

```
T`jJvV`iIuU
Ti01`uUp`vVp`[a-z]+
s(s*[a-zA-Z])
ſ$1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApUYGpKdlZgaUl1VQpUaTAxYHVVcGB2VnBgW2Etel0rCnMocypbYS16QS1aXSkKxb8kMQ&input=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) (The first line enables a linefeed-separate test suite.)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.5, <s>124</s> <s>116</s> <s>111</s> <s>118</s> <s>125</s> <s>144</s> 142 bytes:

```
import re;lambda k:re.sub("J|j|(?<![a-zA-Z])[uU]|(?<=[a-zA-Z])[Vv]|(?<!s)s(?=[a-zA-Z])",lambda g:dict(zip('jJuUvVs','iIvVuUſ'))[g.group()],k)
```

Well, this seems like the perfect job for *regular expressions*!

Comment: You can use `J|j` instead of `[Jj]`

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 154

Using parseInt to identify alphabetic characters. Note: casually but luckily `parseInt('undefined',36)|0` is < 0

```js
s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>((n=v(c))-19?n==31&p>9?'uU':n!=30|p>9?c=='s'&s[i-1]!=c&v(s[i+1])>9?'?':c+c:'vV':'iI')[p=n,c<'a'|0],p=0,v=c=>parseInt(c,36)|0).join``
```

**Less golfed**

```js
s=>
  [...s].map(
  (c,i)=>
  ((n=v(c))-19
  ?n==31&p>9
    ?'uU'
    :n!=30|p>9
      ?c=='s'&s[i-1]!=c&v(s[i+1])>9
        ?'ſ'
        :c+c
      :'vV'
  :'iI')[p=n,c<'a'|0],
  p=0,
  v=c=>parseInt(c,36)|0
).join``
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>[...s].map((c,i)=>((n=v(c))-19?n==31&p>9?'uU':n!=30|p>9?c=='s'&s[i-1]!=c&v(s[i+1])>9?'ſ':c+c:'vV':'iI')[p=n,c<'a'|0],p=0,v=c=>parseInt(c,36)|0).join``

out=(a,b,c)=>O.textContent+=a+'\n'+b+'\n'+c+'\n\n'

ti='Christian Reader, I have for thy use collected this small Concordance, with no small labour. For being to comprise much in little roome, I was to make choyse of the most principall and usefull places, and to rank them under such words as I thought most essentiall and materiall in the sentence, because the scant roome allotted unto me, would not permit that I should expresse them under every word in the verse, as it is the manner in large Concordances.'
to='Chriſtian Reader, I haue for thy vſe collected this ſmall Concordance, with no ſmall labour. For being to compriſe much in little roome, I was to make choyſe of the moſt principall and vſefull places, and to rank them vnder ſuch words as I thought moſt eſsentiall and materiall in the ſentence, becauſe the ſcant roome allotted vnto me, would not permit that I ſhould expreſse them vnder euery word in the verſe, as it is the manner in large Concordances.'
r=F(ti)
out(to==r?'OK':'KO',ti,r)

test=`Joy         Ioy
joy         ioy
Universe    Vniuerſe
universe    vniuerſe
Success     Succeſs
successfull ſucceſsfull
Supervise   Superuiſe
supervise   ſuperuiſe
Super-vise  Super-viſe
I've        I've
majors      maiors
UNIVERSE    VNIUERSE
0universe   0vniuerſe
0verify     0verify
I0ve        I0ve
_UU_          _VU_
_VV_          _VU_
ss_         ſs_`
.split('\n').map(t=>{
  var [i,o]=t.split(/\s+/),r=F(i)
  out(o==r?'OK':'KO',i,r)
})
```

```css
#O {width:90%; overflow:auto; white-space: pre-wrap}
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 111 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/[a-z]+/gi,w=>w.replace(/j|J|^u|^U|\Bv|\BV|ss|s(?!$)/g,c=>"iIvVuUſ"["jJuUvVs".search(c)]||"ſs"))
```

Explanation: Because JavaScript regexp has no lookbehind, I instead break up the string into words, which then allows me to use `^` and `\B` as negative and positive letter lookbehinds. `ss` is dealt with by matching separately, with the slightly awkward replacement expression which takes fewer bytes than either replacing only the first character of `c` or adding an extra `s` to both strings and using the matching substring.

Comment: `c=>"iIvVuUſ"["jJuUvVs".search(c)]||"ſs"` is nice. 

Answer (score 0):

### CJam (<strike>89</strike> 88 bytes)

```
{32|_'`>\'{<*}:A;SqS++3ew{_1="jJuUvVs"#[-4_{_0=A!3*}_{_0=A3*}_{_)A\0='s=>268*}W]=~f^1=}%
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B32%7C_'%60%3E%5C'%7B%3C*%7D%3AA%3BSqS%2B%2B3ew%7B_1%3D%22jJuUvVs%22%23%5B-4_%7B_0%3DA!3*%7D_%7B_0%3DA3*%7D_%7B_)A%5C0%3D's%3D%3E268*%7DW%5D%3D~f%5E1%3D%7D%25&input=Joy%0Ajoy%0AUniverse%0Auniverse%0ASuccess%0Asuccessful%0ASupervise%0Asupervise%0ASuper-vise%0AI've%0Amajors%0AUNIVERSE%0A0universe%0A0verify%0AI0ve%0A_U%0A_V%0Ass_)

I never understood why CJam doesn't have regexes, but since it doesn't here's a solution which doesn't use them.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 85 + 1 = 86 bytes

Run with `ruby -p` (+1 byte for `p` flag). Takes input on stdin.

```ruby
gsub(/j|(?<=^|[^a-z])u|(?<=[a-z])v|(?<=^|[^s])s(?=[a-z])/i){$&.tr"jJsUuVv","iIfVvUu"}
```

Run the tests on ideone (wrapped in a lambda there because you can't give flags to ideone): http://ideone.com/AaZ8ya